# Difference between this and window

Tags: coffeescript, export

Imagine that coffeescript class :

```
class Batman

  constructor: ->

    alert "Batman is awesome"
```

I think it's a rookie question, but what's the real difference between :

```
class @Batman

  constructor: ->

    alert "Batman is awesome"
```

and

```
class window.Batman

  constructor: ->

    alert "Batman is awesome"
```

Comment: `class window.Batman` explicitly puts it in `window`, `class @Batman` puts it in `@` which may or may not be `window`. You can define a class in whatever scope suits you after all.

Comment: in global context this == window, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your coffeescript using the '-c' argument and see what you get:

```
(function() {
    /// Your code here
}).call(this);
```

That `this` there is the context of the function wrapper being called, and becomes the `this` object inside your coffeescript module.

In the context of a browser, your module is initialized with the global `this = window`; in the context of a Node or IoJS, `this = global`, the global context of execution; in the context of plv8, `this = role`, a per-execute object that contains security information (since plv8 is basically node run inside a SQL server, this is important to have).

`class window.Batman` explicitly attaches your Batman class to a window object (which means you no longer have isomorphic code you can use everywhere); `class @Batman` attaches it to the local context, which can be, well, whatever you want it to be.

All in all, as a best practice, attaching stuff to VM-supplied contexts (like the browser, your node instance, your database) is generally *not a good idea*, and you should find a better way to instantiate your code and pass it from module to module.